# How to help mypy understand "if isinstance else" structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I use a simple method for handling arguments that can either be strings or lists of strings. It is intentionally not robust to errors, but is a quick one-liner.

This method works fine in normal Python, but mypy does not handle its types well and raises an error:

```py
def dosomething(ext: Union[str, Iterable[str]] = ".txt"):
    exts: Tuple[str, ...] = (ext, ) if isinstance(ext, str) else ext
```

Error: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "object", variable has type "Tuple[str, ...]")`

Investigating the issue, I see that mypy does not manage to reduce the available type options with the *if isinstance else* structure:

```py
def dosomething(ext: Union[str, Iterable[str]] = ".txt"):
    exts = (ext, ) if isinstance(ext, str) else ext
    reveal_type(exts)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.object'
```

Seeing mypy fall back to `object` is a surprise to me, but I suspect this may be because a `str` is also `Iterable[str]`.

I would like to find a way to avoid this surprising situation by helping mypy while keeping the simplicity.

Comment: I am not sure, but seems `exts: Tuple[str, ...] = (ext, ) if isinstance(ext, str) else ext` says: if `ext` is of type `str` then it should be a tuple (`(ext,)`) but else it should be `ext` itself, which is not a tuple, but `str | iterable over str`, so the type of `exts` look wrong, is not it?

Comment: I agree the `(ext, )` behind `isinstance(ext, str)` is easily inferrable as `Tuple[str, ...]` (or `Tuple[str])`. But the `else` part should allow mypy to remove `str` from the possible types in the `Union[str, Iterable[str]]`, leaving only `Tuple[str, ...]` for both parts.

Comment: Such treating should be wrong: the type must describe all possible inhabited values: in the case it must be a sum of types (ie, union).

Comment: If true that would be a shame and incorrect behaviour. TypeScript demonstrates the correct behaviour with a phrase such as `var exts = (ext instanceof String) ? [ext] : ext;` (where `ext: String|String[]`) and correctly infers that the `: ext` part can only contain `String[]`.

Comment: `ext: String|String[]` - this. It's correct type which covers both cases: `ext` and `[ext]`. So, I think, you should to try the same in Python.

Comment: The TypeScript also works with the general `Iterable<String>`, but your comment helped me understand your first comment better. Replacing `ext` with `tuple(ext)` was not enough however. Also needed to use `tuple(ext, )` instead of `(ext, )` to avoid the fixed-size `Tuple[str]`. If you add an answer pointing this direction I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the issue of how mypy infers the type for conditional expressions. In simple contexts the expression `a if predicate else b` is inferred to be the supertype of `a` and `b`. In the case of `str` and `Iterable[str]` this is `builtins.object`.

```
x = reveal_type(1 if bool() else "str")
# Revealed type is 'builtins.object'
```

One exception is if mypy can resolve the predicate to True or False, then the type gets narrowed to the correct branch:

```
x = reveal_type(1 if True else "str")
# Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```

One would expect that `isinstance` checks could be resolved to True or False by mypy, but it seems that this has not been implemented yet. I think it would be a very reasonable feature request.

However, we can make use of a nice feature of conditional expression typing, which is that it is context aware. So if the conditional expression is used in a context where a different type is expected, and both sides of the conditional fulfill that type, then type checking passes. This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5392) in the context of Union types, but in your case both branches satisfy `Iterable[str]`:

```
exts: Iterable[str] = (ext, ) if isinstance(ext, str) else ext
```

So the key is just specifying the type of `exts` explicitely.